# Can anyone report experiences with HWUT for unit testing?

Tags: c, unit-testing

- Can anyone report experiences with that HWUT tool  (http://hwut.sourceforge.net)?
- Has anyone had experiences for some longer time?
- What about robustness?
- Are the features like test generation, state machine walking, and Makefile   generation useful?
- What about execution speed? Any experience in larger projects?
- How well does code coverage measurments perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the idea of testing by comparing program output, which makes it easy to start writing tests, and also works well when scaling the project later on. Combined with makefile generation it is really easy to set up a test.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using HWUT since several years for software unit testing for larger automotive infotainment projects. It is easy to use, performance is great and it does indeed cover state machine walkers, test generation and make-file generation, too. Code coverage is working well. What I really like about HWUT are the state machine walker and test generation, since they allow to create a large amount test cases in very short time. I highly recommend HWUT.

Answer (score 3):

Much faster than commercial tools, which can save a lot of time for larger projects!

Answer (score 2):

I used HWUT to test multiple software components. It is really straight forward and as a software developer you don't have to click around in GUIs. You can just create a new source code file (*.c or whatever) and your test is nearly done. 
This is very handy when using a version control. You just have to check in the "test.c" file, the Makefile and the results of the test - that's it no need to check in binary files.

I like using the generators which HWUT offers. By using them it is easy possible to create ten thousands (or even more) testcases. Which is very handsome if you want to test the border conditions of e.g. a convert function.